# Windows Mobile (MFC). How convert an image with alpha-channel from CImageList to CBitmap?

Tags: mfc, windows-mobile, alpha, blend, blending

I have subclassed CBitmapButton to create my own button with an overrided function DrawItem. Here is the code from it and it works:

```
CDC *pDC = &dc;
CDC memDC;
memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
CBitmap m_Bmp;
m_Bmp.LoadBitmap(IDB_ARROW);
CBitmap *temp = memDC.SelectObject(&m_Bmp);
BLENDFUNCTION blend;
blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
blend.BlendFlags = 0;
blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
AlphaBlend(pDC->m_hDC, pt.x, pt.y, 85, 85, memDC.m_hDC, 0, 0, 85, 85, blend);
dc.SelectObject(&temp);
```

The problem is that all the images are already loaded and stored in CImageList. And I don't know how to convert them.

Maybe something wrong in CImageList creation:
m_LargeImg.Create(365, 85, ILC_COLOR32, 4, 0);

```
    ImageWork::get().addBitmapToList(IDB_MAIN_MENU_ICON1, &m_LargeImg);
    ImageWork::get().addBitmapToList(IDB_MAIN_MENU_ICON2, &m_LargeImg);
    ImageWork::get().addBitmapToList(IDB_MAIN_MENU_ICON3, &m_LargeImg);
    ImageWork::get().addBitmapToList(IDB_MAIN_MENU_ICON4, &m_LargeImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you shouldn't try to convert them.  If you just want to craw them, try using one of the image list draw functions like CImageList::DrawIndirect which supports Alpha blending and such. It might be the only thing you need.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Maybe it is because of Winmobile's MFC is trimmed (DrawIndirect has 9 parameters instead of 12). So can you put a concrete example?